# Unexpected behavior in Python recursive generator with izip

Tags: python, recursion, generator, subset

I've written a function called `size_subsets` that returns all subsets of a certain size, when passed a list of cities (numbers). However, restating the function using `izip()` instead of two for-yield blocks completely breaks the behavior.

The second method below restates the first method using `izip()`, but for some reason it returns nothing at the top level. Can anyone help me figure out why this is?

Print statements show that SOME (not all) of the correct subsets do get yielded at the bottom-most level of the recursion in `size_subsets_broken`, but even these aren't making it to the top level for some reason.

```py
def size_subsets(cities, size, sofar):
    if not size:
        yield sofar
        return
    elif len(cities) < size:
        return
    else:
        curr_city = cities.pop()
        for a in size_subsets(cities[:], size - 1, sofar | {curr_city}):
            yield a
        for b in size_subsets(cities[:], size, sofar):
            yield b


def size_subsets_broken(cities, size, sofar):
    if not size:
        yield sofar
        return
    elif len(cities) < size:
        return
    else:
        curr_city = cities.pop()
        inclusive = size_subsets_broken(cities[:], size - 1, sofar | {curr_city})
        exclusive = size_subsets_broken(cities[:], size, sofar)

        for incl_subset, excl_subset in izip(inclusive, exclusive):
            yield incl_subset
            yield excl_subset


print list(size_subsets([1, 2, 3], 2, set()))           # [set([2, 3]), set([1, 3]), set([1, 2])]
print list(size_subsets_broken([1, 2, 3], 2, set()))    # []
```

Comment: Your first method yields all the `a` values, followed by all the `b` values. Your second method alternates between them. Do you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you misunderstand how `izip()` works.  It just plain stops when the *shortest* input iterable is exhausted, and there's no reason to believe that your `inclusive` and `exclusive` always have the same length.

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> for i in izip(range(10), [6]):
...     print i
(0, 6)

>>> for i in izip(range(10), []):
...     print i
```

Note that there's only one output in the first example, and no output at all in the second.  That's all expected.

### DETAILS

The top-level call to `size_subsets_broken()` creates a generator-iterator (`gi`) object.  The call to `list()` forces the latter to do something.

It creates `inclusive` and `exclusive` `gi` objects, with arguments (ignoring `sofar`) `[1, 2], 1` and `[1, 2], 2`.  `izip()` then attempts to combine them.

`izip()` first tries to get a value from `inclusive` (which eventually fails to deliver anything, which is why the top-level `gi` never yields anything either - indeed, it never even attempts to force `exclusive` to yield anything, because `inclusive` is empty - `izip()` "just plain stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted").

Recall that the arguments to the top-level `inclusive` were `[1, 2], 1`.  It creates `gi` objects for `[1], 0` and `[1], 1`.  *Its* `izip()` pushes the `[1], 0` branch to yield a value, which it does, via the `if not size` test.  So its `izip()` goes on to push the `[1], 1` branch for a value.

That in turn creates `[], 0` and `[], 1` `gi` branches.  Another layer of `izip()` pushes the first of those to yield a value (again via the `if not size` test), but the second branch yields no value because of `if len(cities) < size: return`.  So the `izip()` one level up gives up, and the `gi` it belongs to yields nothing.

Which propagates up the chain:  at each level, `izip()` finds at least one empty iterator, so the body of the `for ... in izip(...):` loop is never entered (at any level).

This isn't a problem with `izip()`, by the way.  It simply doesn't make sense to *try* to use `izip()` in this algorithm.

Comment: That's right, thanks. In this case I'm simply trying to exhaust both generators, not iterate through them in parallel until the shortest generator was exhausted.

I was trying to save a few lines of code by using `izip()`, but that's simply not what `izip` is used for. Thanks much!

Comment: You could instead use `itertools.chain(inclusive, exclusive)`, which exhausts its input iterables one at a time, left to right.